# Dynamic functions from class name

Tags: php, laravel, magic-function

I want to under stead something about how Laravel does create the magic functions based on the Facade classes. Now what I want is a central class within the magic functions is created based on class names. For example:

```
// Example main class
class Facade 
{
    public function __construct(array $aliases = [])
    {
        $this->aliases = $aliases;
    }

    public function load()
    {
        // Do some magic...
    }
}

// Example Facade subclass
class Navigation 
{
    public function items(string $name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
}

// Array with aliases
$aliases = [
    'navigation' => 'App\Facades\Navigation',
];
new Facade($aliases);

// Then I want to call everywhere:
echo navigation()->items('name'); == 'name'
```

How can I do this, I can't find anything about how Laravel this does.

Answer (score 0):

Define PHP autoloader instead of the Facade class:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $aliases = [
        'navigation' => 'App\Facades\Navigation',
    ];

    if (array_key_exists($class_name, $aliases) {
        include $aliases[$class_name] . '.php';
    }
});
```

And then call your class by (pay attention to the missing brackets):

```
echo navigation->items('name');
```

For more info - [PHP autoload doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only thing I see your are including the file. But all my classes/files are already loaded by the composer autoloader. Also the navigation is not a function:  ```navigation()->items();```.